# Animation with @keyframes is not working in Chrome

Tags: css, animation

This css seems to work fine in Firefox, but not in chrome

```
.animate {
    animation: blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes blink { 
   50% { border-color: red; background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);} 
}
-webkit-@keyframes blink { 
   50% { border-color: red; background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);} 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/18qtvfo0/

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ultimate problem is the selector used is incorrect - which is a simple typographical error and also earned a close vote!

```
-webkit-@keyframes
```

Should be the following, with the @ sign at the start,

```
@-webkit-keyframes
```

The original fiddle also fails to run correctly (anywhere) because the DIV is missing the 'animate' class - here is a [corrected version](http://jsfiddle.net/18qtvfo0/1/) that works in Firefox and Chrome/WebKit.